# trying to calculate the total overall weight of available items in my dictionary's not sure how to calculate in python 3 as keeps error dict_values

Tags: dictionary

weight = {"pencil" : "10", "pen" : "20", "paper" : "4", "eraser" : "80" }

available = {"pen" : "3", "pencil" : "5", "eraser" : "2", "paper" : "10"}

overall_weight = 0

for key, value in weight.items():

```
if key in available:
    overall_weight = weight.values() * available.values()
    print (overall_weight)
```

print("Overall weight:", overall_weight)

Comment: Better search before share information. Stackoverflow is not a freelancer

Comment: sorry i did search and knew i had to cast the values to an int to make it work however i was attempting to cast both values to an in which returned the same error in the code and i am still learning how the code interacts with everything properly didn't realise that you only needed to cast 1 value to int to allow it to then multiply the dict value of the second dict but thanks for attempting to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the values to int. This should work:

```
weight = {"pencil" : "10", "pen" : "20", "paper" : "4", "eraser" : "80" }
available = {"pen" : "3", "pencil" : "5", "eraser" : "2", "paper" : "10"}

overall_weight = 0

for key, value in weight.items():
    if key in available:
        currA = int(value)
        overall_weight += int(available[key]) * int(value)
        print (overall_weight)

print("Overall weight:", overall_weight)
```

Comment: i have a question that you might be able to point me in the right direction if i needed to check multiple user inputs and also store the values of that user inputs i know i can do a while loop to check and make sure that the input is only a positive int but is there a way to condense my code instead of question 1 (run check while loop) question 2 (seperate while loop) question 3 (seperate while loop) ? i have been tryiny to loop for a good answer hope you can hlep

Comment: @JAI You could ask for input 1, then 2, then 3, then check all of them and if at least one is not ok, output an error message asking the user to restart. But in all cases, you need a while loop as long as you want the user to enter correct values, there is no escaping this. Your solution is actually better. What you also can do is create an `ask_question` method that takes the text as parameter, put the check and while loop in there then call it 3 times with different text. Check [this site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this kind of question ;)